# Can't add ZFS to 17.10

Tags: kernel, 17.10, lenovo, zfs

I'm trying to install ZFS on a 17.10 install on my Lenovo laptop and the zfs module is not loading. I suspect this may be because I'm using a different kernel to resolve the corrupted BIOS issue I encountered earlier. Here is a scrape of the relevant commands:

```
root@kigelia:~# apt install zfsutils-linux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-32 linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-zed
Suggested packages:
  nfs-kernel-server samba-common-bin zfs-initramfs | zfs-dracut
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-zed zfsutils-linux
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 957 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,286 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libuutil1linux amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [46.3 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libnvpair1linux amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [35.2 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libzpool2linux amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [387 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libzfs2linux amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [119 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 zfsutils-linux amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [329 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 zfs-zed amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [41.2 kB]
Fetched 957 kB in 0s (2,026 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package libuutil1linux.
(Reading database ... 332030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libuutil1linux_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuutil1linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvpair1linux.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libzpool2linux.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libzpool2linux_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzpool2linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libzfs2linux.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libzfs2linux_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzfs2linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfsutils-linux.
Preparing to unpack .../4-zfsutils-linux_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-zed.
Preparing to unpack .../5-zfs-zed_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfs-zed (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libuutil1linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libzpool2linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libzfs2linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.wants/zfs-import-cache.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-import-cache.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.wants/zfs-mount.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-mount.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-share.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-share.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zfs.target → /lib/systemd/system/zfs.target.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for zfs-import-cache.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status zfs-import-cache.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
Job for zfs-share.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status zfs-share.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
Setting up zfs-zed (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zed.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/zfs.target.wants/zfs-zed.service → /lib/systemd/system/zfs-zed.service.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
root@kigelia:~# zpool create -f tank -O compression=lz4 -m /test /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5002538d40dca5d9-part11
The ZFS modules are not loaded.
Try running '/sbin/modprobe zfs' as root to load them.
root@kigelia:~# /sbin/modprobe zfs
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.3-041503-generic
root@kigelia:~#
```

Here is the kernel and available modules.

```
hbarta@kigelia:~$ uname -a
Linux kigelia 4.15.3-041503-generic #201802120730 SMP Mon Feb 12 07:31:14 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
hbarta@kigelia:~$ find /lib/modules -name "*zfs*"
/lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
/lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
hbarta@kigelia:~$
```

Should I switch back to a mainstream kernel? File a bug report against the special kernel? Add modules to the kernel I'm running?

I'd appreciate suggestions on the best course of action (as well as pointers instructions for doing this properly.)

Thanks!

Edit.0: I booted Debian Stretch on this laptop and performed the same steps. I noted that the install of the ZFS utilities included 'zfs-dkms' which was not a dependency on Ubuntu. I then booted Ubuntu and attempted to install this package. The process reported some errors and then hung. The scrape from the terminal window is

```
hbarta@kigelia:~$ sudo apt install zfs-dkms
[sudo] password for hbarta: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-32 linux-headers-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-32-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  spl spl-dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  spl spl-dkms zfs-dkms
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,486 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 spl-dkms all 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1 [385 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe amd64 zfs-dkms all 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1 [1,081 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/universe amd64 spl amd64 0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1 [19.5 kB]
Fetched 1,486 kB in 0s (3,350 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package spl-dkms.
(Reading database ... 332214 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../spl-dkms_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking spl-dkms (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up spl-dkms (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Loading new spl-0.6.5.11 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.3-041503-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.3-041503-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.15.3-041503-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.3-041503-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/spl/0.6.5.11/build/make.log for more information.
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-dkms.
(Reading database ... 332501 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-dkms_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking zfs-dkms (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package spl.
Preparing to unpack .../spl_0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking spl (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up spl (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up zfs-dkms (0.6.5.11-1ubuntu3.1) ...
WARNING: Building ZFS module on an unknown kernel.
Loading new zfs-0.6.5.11 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.3-041503-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.3-041503-generic
configure: error: 
    *** Please make sure the kmod spl devel <kernel> package for your
    *** distribution is installed then try again.  If that fails you
    *** can specify the location of the spl objects with the
    *** '--with-spl-obj=PATH' option.
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.15.3-041503-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.3-041503-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/zfs/0.6.5.11/build/make.log for more information.
hbarta@kigelia:~$ find /lib/modules -name "*zfs*"
/lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
/lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-21-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs
/lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs/zfs.ko
hbarta@kigelia:~$
```

Comment: I can't help you in detail. Maybe DKMS may need some configuration: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS

Comment: Hi davidbaumann - thanks for the tip. I looked at the link and don't care to dig that deep into DKMS. I added some information to my post. At this point I'm more interested in proceeding with ZFS related testing than spending a lot of time debugging this problem.

Thanks!